# Using multiple classes in one element and specificity

Tags: css, css-specificity

Just wondering when you use multiple classes on the one element such as `class="foo bar"` and those classes are setup as below:

```
.foo {
    margin-right: 10px;
}


.bar {
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Which class will have specificity? Will the margin be 10px or 0px?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It works based on precedence within the CSS. Therefore the item to occur most recently will override any previous styles.

**CASE 1**

```
.red  { background : red; }
.blue  { background : blue; }
```

`class = 'red blue'` would be **blue** in this instance.

**CASE 2**

```
.blue  { background : blue; }
.red  { background : red; }
```

`class = 'blue red'` would be **red** in this instance.

**[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/0wc5txfm/)**

Comment: Great thanks. I think I got it, but since you named your classes red and blue rather than foo and bar it's a little confusing which is which haha

Comment: Stellar Answer; Here is another fiddle forked from yours with another example http://jsfiddle.net/ccatto/KZdJK/107/ displaying CSS precedence order example

Answer (score 8):

Also, if you wish to target the element who has *only* both classes, you can use this syntax:

```
<ul>
  <li class="foo first">Something</li>
  <li class="foo">Somthing else</li>
  <li class="foo">Something more</li>
</ul>

.foo {
  color: red;
}
.foo.first {
  color: blue
}
```

Answer (score 4):

A single class name carries the same weight. In such a scenario, the rule that is listed first will be overwritten by the second, and hence, the element will have `margin-right: 0px;`

Here is a [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/cc7PX/) using `color` instead of margin, because it's easier to visualize. The value specified in `bar` will be chosen by the browser.

Answer (score -2):

In addition, more "specific" class will override a more generic one:

HTML:

> ```
> <div class="foo">
>     <div class="bar">Hello World!</div>
> </div>
> ```

With the following CSS:

```
.foo .bar { margin-left:25px }
.bar { margin-left:0px }
```

Notice how the inner div still has 25px margin to the left?

Also, read up on "!important" argument after providing the value:

```
.bar { margin-left:0px!important }
```

Check out

Comment: Yeah..... already knew about the specificity between more "specific" stuff, just wasn't sure about using two classes that weren't any more specific.

Comment: All classes are equally specific. It is the *combination* of two class selectors that makes `.foo .bar` more specific than `.bar` alone.